# Exception thrown: 'Bloomberglp.Blpapi.NotFoundException' in Bloomberglp.Blpapi.dll

Tags: api, bloomberg

I am using the Bloomberg API and getting this error in VS.  Its not crashing the program but I see the errors in the output window.  I just want to make sure things are running smoothly and I'm concerned there is something wrong.  Does anyone know what this is or how I can get more details about it?

```
                switch (eventObj.Type)
                {
                    case Event.EventType.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
                        Debug.WriteLine("");
                        Debug.WriteLine("hit subscription DATA");
                        foreach (Message msg in eventObj.GetMessages())
                        {
                        }
                }
```

this error
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in Bloomberglp.Blpapi.dll
gets produced on the for-each message in my code.  How can I see details on this so I can fix the issue?

[image: error picture]

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: HELP HELP told me... "this error is because you are looking for an element that does not exist in the response".  how can I get VS to give me more details above error?  as of now VS does not pause on this error... it just skips over with the output message and continues

Comment: have you tried to debug step by step the part of your code that parses the response received from the Bloomberg API? There should be a code somewhere that tries to get the elements of the response and according to what the help desk told you, you try to fetch an element that does not exist.

Comment: i put some of my code above and noted where the error gets produced... on the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm summarizing the information from the extensive comment discussion for future readers:

Make sure you're only iterating over messages of events that are of type `SUBSCRIPTION_DATA`, you should change your code to check the type of the event before handling it:

```
Event eventObj = session.NextEvent();
switch (eventObj.Type)
{
    case Event.EventType.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
        foreach (Message msg in eventObj.GetMessages()) 
        { ... }
        break;
    default:
        HandleOtherEvent(eventObj);
        break;
}
```

To get VS to halt on any exception in any thread, check everything in "Exception Settings" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

You can correlate a subscription event with a subscription using the correlation ID. Check which correlation ID the event has when VS halts on an exception then find out which security the subscription is on, create a sample test and discuss with Bloomberg's HELP HELP.

Per comments below, OP has discussed with HELP HELP that told him/her that this is a Bloomberg issue that has been resolved in the latest API library. Installing the latest library has fixed the issue.

Comment: after your suggestion I changed my code above... after testing, the error occurs ONLY in .SUBSCRIPTION_DATA... soon as its hits the for/each.  I'm sending about 500 markets in the subscription, and based on the error it has a problem with about 30 of the markets.

Comment: Try to get VS to halt on this error by doing ctrl-alt-E and checking everything. Can you paste the exception details here?

Comment: Exception settings

Comment: thanks for the explanation... I just posted a picture of the exception details.  do they mean anything to you?

Comment: System.IO.IOException occurred
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Bad data length for smart field
  Source=Bloomberglp.Blpapi
  StackTrace:
       at Bloomberglp.Blpapi.impl.infr.msg.SelfDescribingTickFieldHeader.streamIn(ByteBufferInputStream bbis)
  InnerException:

Comment: This sounds more and more like a problem with the data being sent or its parsing. You should try to identify which security subscription is causing this by using the correlation ID. Assuming you're assigning a correlation ID to every subscription, when VS breaks on the exception, check what's the correlation ID of the subscription and then find out what's the security. Then create a simple code sample that only subscribes to that security, make sure that it consistently gives this exception and send to HELP HELP.

Comment: thanks... let me try that. as I'm working on that right now, are these types of errors a big deal?  is this something I should be spending my time on trying to find the exact issue?

Comment: Can't be sure but I'm concerned that you're not really subscribing to all the securities that you think you are or are not receiving all the events from the subscriptions you have. That's probably a big deal.

Comment: to be honest thats why I started doing this investigation... I feel like data I should be receiving, for some reason I am missing.  thanks!  let me try what you said and I'll come back

Comment: thanks for all your help!!! taking your advice I gave a specific market to bloomberg and this is their response...BLOOMBERG HELP DESK : I actually found another report of that same issue you just reported. The programmers have fixed the issue, but the fix is available in the latest version of the libraries (v3.8.10), which can be downloaded from https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/